# The OpenForm was cancelled error has reoccurred

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

The OpenForm has reoccurred in my application. I have decompiled/compact and repaired twice.

Code throwing error:
    'Open Menu form
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu", acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal

The first time I encountered this error, I solved it by changing:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
```

to

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu", acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal.
```

This is my procedure that suffers the exception:

```
Private Sub Login(recordSet As DAO.recordSet, PERSAL As String, Password As String)
On Error GoTo Login_ErrHandler

'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
If Not (recordSet.EOF And recordSet.BOF) Then
    recordSet.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit

    'See if credentials match data
    Do
        If (recordSet!User_ID = PERSAL And recordSet!Password = Password) Then

           'Open Menu form
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu"
           ' Form_Menu.op

            recordSet.Close 'Close the recordset
            Set recordSet = Nothing 'Clean up

            'Close Login form
            DoCmd.Close acForm, "Login"

            Exit Do
        End If

        recordSet.MoveNext

        If (recordSet.EOF Or recordSet.BOF) Then
            MsgBox "Your credentials are incorrect or you are not registered."

            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    'Match the values entered for PERSAL nr. and password fields with a row in User table

Else

    MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."

     recordSet.Close 'Close the recordset
     Set recordSet = Nothing 'Clean up

End If

Form_Login.txtUser_ID.SetFocus

Login_ErrHandler:
If Err = 2501 Then
    'MsgBox "No data to display"
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Resume Login_ErrHandler
' Else

 '   MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
End If

End Sub
```

How do I fix this error this time around?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You don't need a loop to check one table row of values. And does *Menu* have any `OnOpen` or `OnLoad` events? Check also its reocordsource.

Comment: Why passing recordset object? Think I would use a DLookup() instead.

Comment: I am new to VBA, June, so my coding won't be tops. Have not heard of DLookup(). The recordset object was all I found when checking how to find table row values.

Comment: Recordset object because I am  looping through the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a parameterized query with the following SQL:

```
PARAMETERS [prmUserId] Text ( 255 ), [prmPassword] Text ( 255 );
SELECT User_ID, Password 
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME
WHERE ((([User_ID])=[prmUserId]) AND (([Password])=[prmPassword]));
```

Assuming the code is behind the Login Form:

```
Private Sub Login(ByVal PERSAL As String, ByVal Password As String)
    On Error GoTo Login_ErrHandler

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdf = CurrentDb().QueryDefs("YourQueryName") 'Change to your query name
        qdf.Parameters("[prmUserId]").Value = PERSAL
        qdf.Parameters("[prmPassword]").Value = Password

    Dim rs As DAO.recordSet
    Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset()

    'No records
    If rs.EOF Then
        MsgBox "Your credentials are incorrect or you are not registered."
        Me.txtUser_ID.SetFocus
        GoTo Leave
    End If

    'User found

    'Close Login Form
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSavePrompt

    'Open Form
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu", acNormal, , , acFormPropertySettings, acWindowNormal

Leave:
    On Error Resume Next
        rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
        qdf.Close
    Set qdf = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Login_ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

Comment: Kostas I looked up parameterized query and found it has to do with the SQL Server which I am not using. Does it require the SQL Server?

Comment: It's a simple query in ms-access. Just create the query and paste the SQL provided.

Comment: @Marcus Mackaku Dont forget to change the "YOUR_TABLE_NAME" to the actual name of your table.